# How to run a python code more than once

Tags: python

I'm trying to run this python code more than use by setting the num_runs to 3. And it only is running correctly once. It runs twice but only the first file has data in it.

```
import random
from math import sqrt
import subprocess
import time

# Set clock
START=time.clock()

# Simulation Parameters - num_real_runs is needed to set the range command in python
num_runs=3

# Counter Variable for total numbers of runs
running=1

while (running<num_runs):   

    # Execute mcell Part1
    subprocess.call("mcell -seed "+str(running)+" Scene.main_1.mdl", shell=True)

    # Execute mcell Part2
    subprocess.call("mcell -seed "+str(running)+" Scene.main_2.mdl", shell=True)

    # Calculate elapsed time for executing python script only (in min)
    END=time.clock()
    ELAPSED=(END-START)
    print "Man, it took me only", ELAPSED, "seconds to run the python code!"    
    running+=1
```

Comment: must come from your mcell command.... Try to run them manually you'll probably have the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

It only runs twice because on the third time through the loop, 3 is not less than 3. Change the `while` statement to:

```
while (running<=num_runs):
```